# Knockout js component using 'with' binding not behaving as expected

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.2

I have the following code from the JSFiddle I have setup: https://jsfiddle.net/ktce56hr/2/

```js
var RootViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.rootText = ko.observable('default text');
    this.rootFunc = function() {
        alert("root func!");
    };
}

ko.components.register('root', {
    viewModel: function(model) {
        var self = this;
        this.rootViewModel = model;
        this.title = ko.observable('default title');
    },
    template: { element: 'root_template' }
});

$(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new RootViewModel());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="component: { name: 'root', params: { model: $root } }"></div>

<script id="root_template" type="text/html">
    <div>
        <span data-bind="text: title"></div>
        <div data-bind="with: rootViewModel">
            <input type="text" data-bind="value: rootText" />
            <button data-bind="click: rootFunc">Go</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

When this code is run I receive the following error:

> ```
> Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "with: function (){return rootViewModel }"
> Message: Unable to process binding "value: function (){return rootText }"
> Message: rootText is not defined
> ```

Can someone please explain why I can't set the binding context using the 'rootViewModel' property on my component view model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring the component instance like so:

```html
<div data-bind="component: { name: 'root', params: { model: $root } }"></div>
```

`params` will be the first argument to the viewmodel constructor function. To the viewmodel constructor it looks like this:

```
"model": {
  "rootText": "default text"
}
```

and the viewmodel it returns will be this:

```
{
  "rootViewModel": {
    "model": {
      "rootText": "default text"
    }
  },
  "title": "default title"
}
```

Of course, accessing `title` in your view works. But inside `with: rootViewModel` it won't contain `rootText`.

The fix is trivial:

```html
<div data-bind="component: { name: 'root', params: $root }"></div>
```

```js
var RootViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.rootText = ko.observable('default text');
    this.rootFunc = function() {
        alert("root func!");
    };
}

ko.components.register('root', {
    viewModel: function(model) {
        var self = this;
        this.rootViewModel = model;
        this.title = ko.observable('default title');
    },
    template: { element: 'root_template' }
});

$(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new RootViewModel());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="component: { name: 'root', params: $root }"></div>

<script id="root_template" type="text/html">
    <div>
        <span data-bind="text: title"></div>
        <div data-bind="with: rootViewModel">
            <input type="text" data-bind="value: rootText" />
            <button data-bind="click: rootFunc">Go</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

P.S.: There still is a similar problem with `rootFunc`, but I trust you can sort that out.

Comment: Thanks heaps, misinterpreted another example in the documentation and was stuck with this for longer then I should have been....

Comment: Here's a tip: `<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 4)"></pre>`. Yes, there are more sophisticated tools to debug Knockout (for example the [Knockoutjs context debugger Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/knockoutjs-context-debugg/oddcpmchholgcjgjdnfjmildmlielhof?hl=en)), but simply dumping the current viewmodel to the page is surprisingly effective.